# How to group similar string values with Pandas, and make a new column where similar values all get the same label?

Tags: python, pandas

so I think this can be elaborated perfectly with an example.

Let's say I have this (simplified) dataset:

```
company_name  grouped_vals      
Apple         Apple       
Aplpe         Apple
Appel         Apple
Apple         Apple       
Microsoft     Microsoft     
Microsovt     Microsoft     
Amazon        Amazon    
Amazno        Amazon    
Amazon        Amazon     
Applez        Apple 
Microsoft     Microsoft
Microsoft,    Microsoft 
Appple        Apple 
Apple         Apple 
Appel         Apple 
Amazzon       Amazon  
Amazon inc    Amazon
Microsft      Microsoft
```

I want to use *company_name* as input, and cluster similar values based on the [difflib.sequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) metric. Which takes two strings as input and returns a similarity value. If they are at least 85% similar they should get the value of the most frequent company_name for that company (which should be the correct spelling), which will be the value put in *grouped_vals*. This is basically to alleviate some of the problems in the typo ridden company_name and cluster the same company names which have spelling errors or are alternatively spelled. As you can see in the example we went from 10+ distinct values to only 3 in the grouped_vals column (and the grouped_vals has the correct spelling for every company because correct spelling will be the most frequent value logically in company_name), which is exactly what I want.

I'm assuming the code for such a practice will be in line of:

```
if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'Apple', 'Appple').ratio() > 0.85:
    df.loc[df.company_name=='Appple', grouped_vals] = 'Apple'
```

But I cant get it to work systematically for every company_name in Pandas, also considering the grouped_vals value has to be set to the most frequent company_name for that set of similar company_names values. Anyone has an idea how to do this?